# Finding a matrix that maps the eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix to its orthogonal vector.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be real symmetric $m \times m$ matrix with m distinct eigenvalues and $ v_1, v_2, .....v_m$ be the corresponding eigenvectors.Let C be an $m \times m$ matrix satisfying $\langle Cv_j,v_j\rangle=0$ for $1\le j\le m$. Prove that there exists an $m\times m$ matrix X such that AX-XA=C.

What i have done is as follows:

Let X be any $m \times m $ matrix. Now $\langle Xv_j,v_j \rangle$=$\langle Xv_j,v_j \rangle$
Multiplying both sides by the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ corresponding to $v_j$ we have
$\langle Xv_j,\lambda_jv_j \rangle$=$\langle \lambda_j Xv_j,v_j \rangle$ { since $\lambda_j $ is real}

$\Rightarrow \langle Xv_j,\lambda_jv_j \rangle$=$\langle X\lambda_jv_j,v_j \rangle$

$\Rightarrow \langle Xv_j,Av_j \rangle$=$\langle XAv_j,v_j \rangle$

$\Rightarrow \langle A^tXv_j,v_j \rangle$=$\langle XAv_j,v_j \rangle$ { since A is real}

$\Rightarrow \langle AXv_j,v_j \rangle$=$\langle XAv_j,v_j \rangle$ { since A is symmetric}

$\Rightarrow \langle AXv_j,v_j \rangle-\langle XAv_j,v_j \rangle=0$

$\Rightarrow \langle AXv_j- XAv_j,v_j \rangle=0$

$\Rightarrow \langle Cv_j,v_j \rangle=0$

This is true for all eigenvectors $v_j$ of A hence the statement is proved.

IS MY SOLUTION CORRECT?

Comment: The last step is unclear. You prove that $\langle (AX-XA)v_j,v_j\rangle=0$, and that $C$ has the same property, but you don't show that they are equal. To be more clear, suppose that $C$ is not all zeros. Then, since I can choose any $X$, I choose it to be identity matrix. This means $AI_m-I_mA=O_m\ne C$

Comment: You should somehow produce a matrix $X$ for a given $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to find somehow an $X$ for the given $C$.

**Hint:** $v_1,\dots, v_n$ is an orthogonal basis, transform each matrix to this basis, then $A$ becomes diagonal, and each entity on the diagonal of $C$ is $0$, so $C$ is a linear combination of the matrices which has a single off-diagonal $1$ and all other entries are $0$.
Now basically it's enough to find an $X$ for $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$.

(Note that one can find such an $X$ also for $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$, so the same argument can be extended to prove it for all matrices $C$ which has *zero trace*.)